# Heroku Error: Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch (With axios)

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

This is the full error code:  Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

A lot of answers to this say it has to do with setting your port as heroku does so dynamically, but if im using axios and not server.listen, and require a specific port for the mcsrv api, how would I go about fixing this problem?

I've already tried to set it to process.env.PORT with no avail (as well as using the || statement to set it to a default port)

```
 // Function for getting player counts
require('dotenv').config()

const axios = require('axios')

function pingForPlayers() {

    // Ping API for server data.

    axios.get(`https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/play.lightningshot.net`)
    .then(response => {

        // If it gets a valid response

        if(response.data && response.data.players) {

            let playerCount = response.data.players.online || 0 // Default to zero

            info = `${playerCount}`

            client.channels.get('605543627208392875').setName("Players Online: " + info)

            // Could add console.log for more info, not necessary waste of cache data
        }

        else
            console.log('Could not load player count data for', process.env.MC_SERVER)


    }).catch(err => console.log('Error pinging api.mcsrvstat.us for data:', err))

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your app is not a webapp.

You can add `Procfile` in your source:

```
worker:  node index.js // (or your main file)
```

And change to worker:

- In Heroku dashboard, click tab resources
- [image] and enable worker

Answer (score 0):

this isn't node.js but the issue is on the profile.

Just spent several hours on this coz I did not read the docs at the first place))

if you are developing an app which does not need UI, then use worker instead of web on Procfile.

In the procfile, instead of using:  `web: python app.py`
use this: `worker: python app.py`

after you push everything to heroku git, make sure to: `heroku scale worker=1`